# Store read/write data in assembly similar to filesystem

Tags: file, assembly, operating-system, persistence, non-volatile

I am creating a custom operating system and is there any way to store data (almost like a filesystem) in assembly so that if the computer shuts off and turns back on the data will still be there?

Comment: You can of course write them to any storage device too (like a filesystem), but if it is your actual HW, make sure you write to the device you don't care about content, or that you actually do use it's file system and write valid file (may be very complex for modern filesystems, simple enough for old FAT-like FS). Better don't use actual HW in the first place, and run in some VM/emulator. But NVRAM is almost "instant" (while storage device may take couple of ms for flash drives, or "eons" for mechanical ones) and you can structure the data any way you want (as long as you fit into size).

Answer (score 5):

You can write device drivers for SATA hard drives, USB mass storage, floppy disks, NVMe flash, or whatever else in asm.  You might also be able to use BIOS functions to access them (especially if you're on x86).  But then you have to manage writes in chunks of 512B or 4096B, because those kinds of storage are block-based.

---

A more literal interpretation of the question has an interesting answer: can a store instruction like `mov [mem], eax` put data into persistent storage where a load instruction can get it later (after a power cycle)?

**Yes, if your hardware has some memory-mapped non-volatile RAM**.  (Physically memory-mapped NVRAM like an [NVDIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVDIMM), not like `mmap()` to logically map a file into the virtual memory address space of a process).  See this [answer on Superuser about Intel Optane DC Persistent Memory](https://superuser.com/questions/1389552/can-intel-optane-memory-compensate-for-less-ram/1391391#1391391)

x86 for example has recently gotten more instructions to support NVRAM, like [`clwb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/clwb) to write-back a cache line (all the way to memory) without necessarily evicting it.  Early implementations of `clwb` may just run it like `clflushopt`, though: [@Ana reports that Skylake-X does evict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573776/exclusive-access-to-l1-cacheline-on-x86/51574318?noredirect=1#comment96553954_51574318).

Also, `clflushopt` is a more efficient way to force more cache lines to memory.  Use a memory barrier like `sfence` after a weakly-ordered flush like `clflushopt` to make sure data is in non-volatile RAM before further writes appear.

For a while Intel was going to require `pcommit` as part of making sure data had hit non-volatile storage, [but decided against it](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/09/12/deprecate-pcommit-instruction).  With that in mind, see [Why Intel added the CLWB and PCOMMIT instructions](https://danluu.com/clwb-pcommit/) for more details about using persistent RAM.

IDK what the situation is on architectures other than x86, but presumably NV RAM is / will be usable with ARM and other CPUs, too.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped